# (C#/API) DescribeSObjects call returning only 250 fields

Tags: soql, api, c#

When calling **describeSObjects** on any **sObject** that has more than 250 fields, I am only receiving back 250 fields and I am not sure what to do about it.

I know that there is a hard limit on the number of results returned via a **query** call, and that **queryMore** can be used in a loop to get all of the results, but I cannot figure out how to do this with a **describeSObjectResult** or a **describeSObjects** call. I also have not been able to find any information on how to structure a **query** string that could be used to replace a call to **describeSObjects**.

Please help?

Comment: How many fields are you missing, are you using the latest API version. can you post your code that shows this.

Comment: @superfell I'm not sure why the number of fields I'm missing is relevant. That number is different depending on which sObject I'm calling the describe on. If there are more than 250 fields, I only get 250 fields. The code is literally just a call to describeSObjects with a string array of the sObjects I want.

Comment: Can you see more than 250 fields if you use other tools the rely on `describeSObjects`? The [Web Workbench](https://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Workbench) would be a good place to check and see if you can see the required fields.

Comment: @Daniel Ballinger I know for a fact that there are more than 250 fields on some sObjects. The Case sObject is the primary offender. System.Reflection shows it has 386 Properties, but only 250 are being returned from the describeSObjects call. I have already confirmed that some of the missing fields are simple strings or booleans, and this is not an issue with System.Reflection.PropertyInfo falsely inflating the number.

Comment: @JdinklageMorgoone It might be more to do with API permissions for the given session user. Not everyone can see all fields depending on Permissions/Profiles, etc... If you can check another tool that uses the Partner API to access the field descriptions you can verify if the fields can be accessed.

Comment: @Daniel Ballinger The problem, I've just discovered, is there is a sizable discrepancy between my WSDL and the actual Case table. When attempting to force query for some of the fields that are shown by System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[], I am thrown "Column not present" errors.

Comment: What API version and which API are you using.